# Fetching records taking some time using repository and dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac, unit-of-work

I am creating 1 demo application to study repository and dependency injection.

I am having just 10 to 15 records in my database tables and when reading it is taking some amount of times and i dont know why.is it because of repository or dependency injection??

so Please guide me if you have any suggestions or improvements in my code

This is my Project Architecture:

1) Data Model:This Project contains my EDMX file(Data Model that is data base first approach).

```
public partial class RepositoryDemoEntities : DbContext
    {
        public RepositoryDemoEntities ()
            : base("name=RepositoryDemoEntities ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

2)Repository:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> _entities;
        private RepositoryDemoEntities _context;
        public EfRepository()
        {
            this._context = new RepositoryDemoEntities();
            this._entities = this._context.Set<T>();
        }

        public T GetById(object id)
        {
            _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            return this._entities.Find(id);
        }
        public IQueryable<T> Table
        {
            get
            {
                return this._entities;
            }
        }
      }
    //And other methods....


public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T GetById(object id); 
        void Insert(T entity);
       IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
     }
```

3)Services:

```
public partial interface IEmployeeService
    {
            IList<Employee> GetAllEmployees();
    }

public partial class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
       private readonly IRepository<Employee> _employeeMasterRepository;
      public EmployeeService(IRepository<Employee> employeeMasterRepository)
    {
        this._employeeMasterRepository = employeeMasterRepository;
    }

     public virtual IList<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        var query = _employeeMasterRepository.Table.ToList();
        return query;
    }
```

4)My Mvc Project:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
           private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
           public HomeController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
        {
            this._employeeService = employeeService;
        }

public ActionResult Index()
        {
          var data=_employeeService.GetAllEmployees() //Taking Some amount of time
        }
    }
```

Dependency injection in autofac config:

```
 public static class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
              builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

 builder.RegisterType<EmployeeService>().As<IEmployeeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

}
```

My Global.asax:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {
          AutofacConfig.RegisterComponents();
        }
```

Comment: Is it just the initial call that is slow, or every call? It's unlikely to be an issue with your DI implementation, but most probably a config/performance issue with EF. How many models do you have in your EDMX and do you have a lot of dependencies with `LazyLoading` enabled?

Comment: Define "..taking some amount of time..." - is it taking seconds, minutes, longer?  How does this compare with how long it takes to query the db directly.  Your sample is pulling back all records in the `Employee` table - how many records?  finally, what does the Employee table look like?  Are you storing large data objects in it (e.g. employee image)?

Comment: yaa initial call is slow.well i am having may be more than 30 models in my edmx.

Comment: If its just the initial call that is slow then you need to look at performance tuning EF or moving to another ORM.

Comment: @MariaPithia If you are referring to "initial timing" then be aware that EF will consume a start up time in the first query. Read more here: http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2012/03/squash-entity-framework-startup-time.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3249719/1565402

Comment: Show us how many relations the Employee entity have and what is your view.

Comment: @BrendanGreen:no i am not storing any large data in my database.let me show you my employee entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the view it is hard to say where your delay is. There are several things to consider:

- DI consume virtually no time here, so do not blame it
- When using ORMs, always pair it with a profiler like EF Profiler from Hibernating Rhinos or DevArt. See SQL queries that are being fired to avoid common issues
- Typical issue is SELECT N+1 problem when you have your relations lazy loaded and each row in, say, employee record view fires a bunch of queries to get related elements (profiler will show this)
- You register PerLifetimeScope, whilst for MVC I would strongly recommend having your DAL dependencies to be registered PerRequest. In this case, your database session will die when request closes and any lazy loading will show up immediately (empty data or crash with null reference exception)
- Entity Framework bothers me with this DbContext black box. Compare it with NHibernate, where we have an ISessionFactory that is expensive to create but you do it once when your application starts, and a lightweight ISession that is cheap to create and it is registered per request.

Comment: sir could you please give me solution for your 4th point in the form of code and any other changes you want to suggest which is strongly recommended?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you have not provided the view code and it is hard to tell what is going on on the database side. Take any profiler on a trial, it is free, see what it tells you.

Comment: Concerning the 4th point, you just need to change your registration from .PerLifetimeScope to .PerRequest. This extension is available if you use Autofac integration with MVC.

Comment: but sir what will be the advantage of doing that??

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, keeping the database connection open outside of the http request scope is a bad practice. In http world you must be atomic and stateless. For the data access, you open a connection when the request starts and you get some data, then close the connection when your request is closed. You return http response and have no open ends. If you ever will have lazy loading issue in your view, it will immediately show up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76977/discussion-between-maria-pithia-and-alexey-zimarev).